# Secure time based one time password over SMS

Tags: hash

I am designing a one time password system, in which I will send the password to the user over some transport (concretely SMS). Once they receive it they will type it into the mobile app. In this way we can verify that the user has access the phone number they gave us.

I want to use a stateless time based one time password. My idea is to take the timestamp at the time of code generation, truncated to say, the last 30 second interval. Then I will hash this timestamp together with a random 128 bit UUID for the user. Then I will interpret the last few bytes of the hash as a 6 digit number for the OTP.

Is this safe, in the sense, that, when someone gives us the correct OTP, I can be sure with high probability that they received it by text? (Did not guess it). I'm happy to assume that the SMS etc is secure.

Thanks

(PS. I don't know which hash functions are best, but I was assuming sha256)

Comment: What is the difference from uniform randomly selecting a 6-digit number?

Comment: I don't exactly know the security difference, that's my question.
From an engineering perspective, my solution is stateless whereas a random 6 digit number must be stored.

Comment: stateless? You need to store the time stamp to regenerate at the server.

Comment: no you don't: you just try the last 2 minutes or whatever. The OTP doesn't last forever

Comment: Ok, so you are content to look for different intervals, it seems that there can be more than one acceptable OTP for you.

Comment: it makes no difference to my question. we can say there is only one interval and one otp.

Comment: Assuming that you don't store the time then you can be stateless. Assuming that the UUID for the user is not known the attacker then Hashing with a secure hash is fine. Can you guarantee that the UUID cannot be guessed? What if an attacker just steals the necessary part from the database and waits(!) for the specific event to attack the target? The threat model is very important for your cause.

Comment: I'm speaking in general terms here. Of course, I can use some extra secret entropy value concatenated with the UUID. Then, I would not need to rely on the secrecy of the UUID.

AFAIU: my idea is secure.